# Request Headers not being set in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cross-domain, cors, cross-domain-policy

I am creating a bookmarklet which makes a cross domain Ajax call. After some digging around, I came across Cross Origin Resource Sharing. Where I have to set request headers on my domain saying that it is okay to do that.

I came across a blog post that explained how to do it in rails. Here is the code for my application.rb

```
before_filter :set_access_control_headers 

def set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end
```

When I try making the call while I am on my domain it sets the correct headers. But when I try from other domains, which is the main purpose for these options, they do not get set.
I get the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mydomain.com/ Origin stackoverflow is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. 
Well this is because it is not being set. From my knowledge this is something to do with the server or do I actually have to change something in my Javascript. Is there an option I am missing?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: This was a long time ago, cannot pint point you to the exact solution but have a look at JSONP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about